# Bathroom faucet handle with no screws

Tags: bathroom, faucet

I need help trying to figure out how to remove this faucet handle. The handle went loose and you cant turn on the water, its rotates freely. I can unscrew that part of the handle but thats it. No idea how to remove the base to try to fix it. There are no visible screws.
Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: Have you checked the underside and see how it is fitted into the sink?

Comment: did you unscrew the handle all the way and look inside?

Answer (score 2):

There is no doubt a larger sized nut and washer around a threaded part of the faucet body that clamps up under the bottom of the rear sink shelf. Once any water piping is removed the nut and washer can be removed and the faucet lifts out from the top.

On some there is just a washer and a retainer clip on the bottom side and then the skirt part of the faucet on the top screws onto the lower part and is tightened down from the top side.